# executing if and else both condition in PHP

Tags: php

Why *if* and *else* both conditions are executing inside `if($flw){ ... }`

After executing the inner `if` condition of the program, the `else` condition is also executing.

this is the class which I am using

```
class follow extends \Thread{

public $follow;
public $query;

public function connect(){
   $my = new \mysqli(SQLHOST, SQLUSER, SQLPASS, SQLDB);
   return $my;
}

public function run(){}

/*****************************************
*sql queries  related to follow system   *
*@param $x follower $y following         *
******************************************/

public function followSql($x, $y){

    $this->query = array(


        'follow' => "INSERT INTO follow(userid, following) VALUES('$x','$y')",

        'unfollow' => "DELETE FROM follow WHERE userid ='$x' AND following='$y'",

        'following' => "SELECT followid FROM follow WHERE userid='".$x."' AND following='".$y."'"
    );

    return $this->query;
}

/*****************************
*  to follow user            *
*  @param $query sql query   *
*****************************/
public function followDoUndo($q){

    try{

        if($this->connect()){

         mysqli_query($this->connect(), $q);
        }
    }catch(Exception $ex){
        var_dump($ex);
    }
}

/***********************************
*  to show user folllowing or not  *
*  @param $query sql query         *
************************************/
public function following($q){

    try{

        if($this->connect()){

            $result = mysqli_query($this->connect(), $q);

            if (is_object($result)) {
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)

                        $this->follow = TRUE;
            }
         return $this->follow;

        }


}catch(Exception $ex){
            var_dump($ex);
        }
    }
}



if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" ){

    $flw = $_POST["flw"];
}



if($flw){
    if($follow->following($follow->followSql($uid,$ud)['following'])){
        $follow->followDoUndo($follow->followSql($uid,$ud)['unfollow']);
        $showText = "+ follow";
    }
    else{
        $follow->followDoUndo($follow->followSql($uid, $ud)['follow']);
        $showText = "following";
    }   
}
```

Comment: it is not that the if and else are executing. it is that you are calling the function twice and checking for a value that you are changing in the else statement (first call) making you fall into the if statement in the second call.

Comment: i have added complete code, have a look @jDo

Comment: @hassanraza Cool cool. Got an answer too, I see :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (something) { //The parent IF

  if (something else) { //The child IF
    //do something
  }

  else { //Runs when the child IF is not true.
    //do another
  }

}
```

Totally, you can simply say this: the inner else is not the else for the parent. It's for the sibling

Comment: but after becoming child if true, program should terminate, but it is going to else condition, why???

Comment: @hassanraza, That's impossible. Please put some hard coded echo step by step to see what's happening